# Как удалить последнюю строку в переменной

Tags: c#

Имеется переменная со строкой

```
 a = @"Last reboot was cold reset.
  Uptime is 12 weeks, 2 days, 14 hours, 9 minutes
SUPPORT_ROOM_sw3#"
```

Каким образом мы можем удалить последнюю строку (SUPPORT_ROOM_sw3#).

### Пример

Такой вариант не подходит так как нужно знать имя того что мы хотим удалить

```
a.Remove(a.LastIndexOf("SUPPOR"));
```

Comment: Через разбиение на массив строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
string a = @"Last reboot was cold reset.
  Uptime is 12 weeks, 2 days, 14 hours, 9 minutes
SUPPORT_ROOM_sw3#";
var lines = a.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse();
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

Или вот так

```cs
int i = a.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
string result = i < 0 ? a : a.Remove(i);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Вопрос в следующем. Как обойти исключение если StartIndex меньше 0. Без try и catch

Comment: @Tand обновил ответ